# Keep leading zero's intact when added to .CSV with I/O enabled

Tags: excel, vba, io

The title is messy, my apologies.  Not sure the best way to word that, so if you a better suggestion, please.

The script I have works, but I'm having trouble keeping the leading zeros. I have tried to insert the .NumberFormat = "@", but I can only do that after I have created the file.  I also tried adding the "'" at the leading zero when it puts the text into the file and it does add it, but doesn't apply it.  It just keeps the "'" in front of the zero.

Suggestions?  Thank you in advance!

Original number: 00099999 ---- 
Currently adds to file as: 99999 ----
If I add "'", it adds to file as: '00099999

Here's the snippet:

```
FName = i & "_INPUT" & ".csv"

If FName = False Then
  Exit Sub 'user cancelled
End If
FNum = FreeFile
Open FName For Output Access Write As #FNum
  For Each ir In range
    If ir > 0 Then
      strtest = ir
      newnum = ExtractNumber(strtest)
    End If

    S = newnum & Chr(9) 'build each line
    S = Left(S, Len(S) - 1) 'remove trailing tab

    Print #FNum, S 'print to file

  Next ir
  Close #FNum
End If
```

Comment: What does your mehtod `ExtractNumber` do?  Also `S = newnum & Chr(9)` and `S = Left(S, Len(S) - 1)` just leave you with `newnum`.  Those two lines cancel each other out.

Comment: Try setting the Calculation mode to manual and see if its working.

Comment: Extractnumber points to a function that reduces a cell to numbers only; including the leading zero's if present.  The rest of the code works as it should and adds the numbers to the spreadsheet, but omits the leading zero's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you testing the CSV file? If you reopen it in Excel, it will remove the leading zeroes at that point - if you open it in Notepad they should still be there, assuming they were written to the file originally.

Comment: Correct, and thank you because I forgot to add that piece.  If I write it to a text file it's fine.  However, I need to be able to manipulate it in excel and that's where I'm having the issue. Suggestions?

Comment: You can't just open the file (unless you prefix the apostrophes) but you can import it, which allows you to specify the field types as Text, or use `Workbooks.Opentext` in code which again allows you to add the FieldInfo as an array

Comment: I decided on the workbooks.opentext using the fieldinfo and that worked.  Thanks!